# okhttp3 memory high after stress test with http2

Tags: spring, memory, okhttp, http2

Excuse me, I'm doing a stress test using http2 with okhttp3 as library
I'm using JMeter as testing tool
My thread is 200 for 300s and ramp up in 30s

I'm using docker as a platform
After stress test, the memory goes up high into 8GB and never go down
I already use code like this

```
> client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
> client.connectionPool().evictAll();
```

And already using singleton for my okhttpclient

But still not go down
Is there any things that I miss?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically JVM programs never release memory until the process exits. It's a side effect of the way the memory is managed.

Comment: So you mean I must close my programs and then the memory will be released?